# Storybook with Tailwind - Tailwind's background images are not resolved

Tags: vue.js, storybook

Tailwind background images are with following syntax:

```
backgroundImage: (theme) => ({
"drop-arrow": "url('/res/public/images/drop_down_arrow.svg')",
...
})
```

where /res is outside the folder ../www/www/res.., but using url it's resolving on the web. The project is already pretty big and I want to introduce storybook. I've added `@storybook/addon-styling` package and did the setup guide. When trying to build storybook, it cannot resolve the images, because they are in another folder.

I've tried to rename
`"drop-arrow": "url('/res/public/images/drop_down_arrow.svg')",` to
`"drop-arrow": "url('../www/www/res/public/images/drop_down_arrow.svg')",`. There was some progress, but I don't want to touch, because it might break some stuff. Is it possible to use custom tailwind config for storybook or resolve properly the assets?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I try a lot of things, but without success. Did you have found a solution?

I have this image extending theme in tailwind.config.js:

```
backgroundImage: {
    'grid': "url('/img/bg-grid.png')",
}
```

If I remove the url pseudo function, storybook start, but stop working the background in the page.

Comment: I just used custom tailwind config (tailwind 3 support multiple configs) specifically for the storybook and use relative path of the icons there (I duplicated the icons in the storybook folder). This is the only solution I succeeded so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `~` to your image path, use relative path here.

```css
backgroundImage: {
    'grid': "url('~/img/bg-grid.png')",
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).